How do I merge two dictionaries together in Robot Framework?
Suppose I have these two dictionaries:
&{dictOne} =  Create Dictionary  key             value             anotherkey  anothervalue
&{dictTwo} =  Create Dictionary  yetanother_key  yetanother_value  finalkey    finalvalue

How could I merge those two dictionaries together into a third one that has both dictOne's and dictTwo's key-value pairs?
{
    'key': 'value',
    'anotherkey': 'anothervalue',
    'yetanother_key': 'yetanother_value',
    'finalkey': 'finalvalue'
}


You use Create Dictionary keyword:
    ${dictOne}  Create Dictionary  key             value             anotherkey  anothervalue
    ${dictTwo}  Create Dictionary  yetanother_key  yetanother_value  finalkey    finalvalue
    ${merged}    Create Dictionary    &{dictOne}    &{dictTwo}
    Log Dictionary    ${merged}

